# Is possible—in Windows 10—to display additional calendars?

Tags: windows, windows-10, calendar

Is possible—in Windows 10—to display additional calendars.

I wish to display a Hebrew calendar.

It is not part of the standard options but I am aware that some experimental features in Windows 10 can be turned on with registry tweaks. Would this be one of them?

Is anyone aware of an option that would allow calendars not listed here?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can add additional calendars in the Calendar app. Settings > calendar settings > Enable alternate calendars > select calendar.

Edit: These settings were moved to the actual calendar app. Open the Calendar app and click the settings gear near the bottom left.

Comment: Where do I find *calendar settings*?

Comment: I edited my original answer. The settings were moved to the Calendar app.

Comment: How about Windows 10 **LTSC**? There is no Calendar app, but Additional Calendar exist.